# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Table

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I am running a spark-submit job in cloudera (CDH 5.13) VM. My job tries to connet hbase table using spark scala. Project is built using Eclipse. In Eclipse job is running fine, but when I try to run spark submit through shell then I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Table.

Error:

```
[cloudera@quickstart bin]$ ./spark-submit --class sparkHiveHbaseInt2 /home/cloudera/Desktop/Demo_Final.jar
24/01/30 02:11:43 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Table
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Table
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 13 more
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
[cloudera@quickstart bin]$
```

This is my code in eclipse to connect to hbase

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{ Row, SaveMode, SparkSession }
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{
  HBaseAdmin,
  Result,
  Put,
  HTable,
  ConnectionFactory,
  Connection,
  Get,
  Scan
}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
object sparkHiveHbaseInt2 extends App {
  //set logging level to error
  Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
  // create spark config object
  val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
  sparkConf.setAppName("Credit_Card_Fraud_Detection")
  sparkConf.setMaster("local[2]")
  sparkConf.set("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083")
  // use spark config object to create spark session
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .config(sparkConf)
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()

  val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()

  conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quoram", "localhost")
  conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181")
  val connection: Connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf)
  val tableName = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf("card_lookup"))

  //SET hive.metastore.schema.verification=true;
  import spark.implicits._
  import spark.sql
  // start writing the hive queries
  val df_ucl = sql("""
            with cte_rownum as
            (
            select card_id,amount,member_id,transaction_dt,
            first_value(postcode) over(partition by card_id order by transaction_dt desc) as postcode,
            row_number() over(partition by card_id order by transaction_dt desc) rownum
            from bigdataproject.card_transactions
            )
            select card_id,member_id,
            round((avg(amount)+ 3* max(std)),0) as ucl ,
            max(score) score,
            max(transaction_dt) as last_txn_time,
            max(Postcode)as last_txn_zip    
            from
            (   select
            card_id,amount,
            c.member_id,
            m.score,
            c.transaction_dt,
            Postcode,
            STDDEV (amount) over(partition by card_id order by (select 1)  desc) std
            from cte_rownum c
            inner join bigdataproject.member_score_bucketed m on c.member_id=m.member_id 
            where rownum<=10
            )a
            group by card_id,member_id
            """)
  val df = df_ucl.select("card_id", "member_id", "ucl", "score", "last_txn_time", "last_txn_zip")

  //df.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("card_lookup")
  //println(sql("""select * from card_lookup""").count())

  println("Dataframe extract is completed");

df.foreach { myRow =>
      {
  var myArray = myRow.mkString(",").split(",") 
  
    var cardId = myArray(0)
    var memberId = myArray(1)
    var ucl  = myArray(2)
    var score  = myArray(3)
    var lastTxnTime = myArray(4)
    var lastTxnZip = myArray(5)
    val row = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(cardId))
    row.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("lkp_data"),Bytes.toBytes("member_id"),Bytes.toBytes(memberId))
    row.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("lkp_data"),Bytes.toBytes("ucl"),Bytes.toBytes(ucl))
    row.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("lkp_data"),Bytes.toBytes("score"),Bytes.toBytes(score))
    row.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("lkp_data"),Bytes.toBytes("last_txn_time"),Bytes.toBytes(lastTxnTime))
    row.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("lkp_data"),Bytes.toBytes("last_txn_zip"),Bytes.toBytes(lastTxnZip))   
    tableName.put(row) 
      }
}
  tableName.close()
  connection.close()
  println("Success");

}
```

Before submitting spark job I am exporting the project from eclipse in the form of JAR.